# enp3s0 (formerly eth0) does not connect anymore

Tags: networking, network-manager

my computer can only connect to my network via wifi for a week now. In NetworkManager’s `journalctl` output, I find:

#### journalctl output

```
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <warn>  [1604507706.0747] dhcp4 (enp3s0): request timed out
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0748] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0748] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0752] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <warn>  [1604507706.0762] device (enp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired Ethernet'
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0766] device (enp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0798] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0799] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed timeout -> done
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0808] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired Ethernet' (a6466101-ff2c-4d4c-b898-de5be7932c85)
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0813] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired Ethernet' (a6466101-ff2c-4d4c-b898-de5be7932c85)
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0814] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0816] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0818] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0824] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 04 17:35:06 aeon NetworkManager[549788]: <info>  [1604507706.0827] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

#### NM output (notification bubbles)

"IP configuration was unavailable"

#### Manual dhclient call

```
root@aeon:~# dhclient -v enp3s0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp3s0/d4:5d:64:52:c9:c1
Sending on   LPF/enp3s0/d4:5d:64:52:c9:c1
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1 (xid=0xf30ecf3e)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
^C
```

### What works

wifi works, dhcp returns in an instant.

### Things I tried

1. changing the dhcp provider in my NetworkManager.conf to internal or dhclient.
2. Deleting old leases in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/`.
3. I made sure I have the empty file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` in place.
4. Tried to create a static network ip connection. Well, it connects, but I do not get any data through.

#### Current `NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq
#dhcp=dhclient
#dhcp=internal

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

#### `lsb`

```
root@aeon:~# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

#### netplan files

```
root@aeon:~# ll /etc/netplan/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 23  2018 ./
drwxrwxr-x 208 root root 20480 Nov  4 20:10 ../
```

---

Ok, I do not know what to do next. I think I had a netplan.io apt-update from 0.99.x to 0.100.x, but downgrading didn’t help either. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: No such file(s).

Comment: Typically, depending on your version, a netplan yaml file exists and hands over all networking tasks to Network Manager. What is your version? `lsb_release -d`

Comment: Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do whenever you are not receiving IP address with a wire cable :

1. Test your network has no short, try another cable.
2. Check visually if pins inside network port are not broken (both side, computer and switch/router)
3. Check network light activity.
4. Try to plug on another network.
5. Try to do a power recycle : power off your computer, unplug the power supply, long press the power button during 30 seconds (of course computer will not powering). Plug back, switch on and test again.

Comment: Thanks, already tried all of that. The physical connection is okay. I also verified it using a cable checker. I can connect via static IP, but do not get any useful data through.

Comment: Thanks, I had to mark this as correct answer – one of the cables inside the wall WAS loose, but only slightly so my cable checker did light up most of the time. Thanks for bringing this up again. Never had a hardware issue before – I say this as a coder :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in a desktop installation, there is a netplan yaml file that effectively hands off networking to Network Manager. You have none. Let's add it and see if connectivity improves. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing and indentation. Proofread carefully twice.

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor. (Ctrl+x)

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: No improvement. But this did not suprise me, as I had mentioned that running `dhclient` will also not work.

Comment: Do you see the available connection at the Network Manager icon? Does it try to connect when you click it? Are there any further clues in: `dmesg | grep -e etwork -e enp`  ?

Comment: Hi… it seems just a cable got loose :( Sorry for the fuzz. Ill mark the other answer as corect.